# How to compare two getJson result in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code to compare the result of getJson by capturing its result from a previous data. But I'm not sure where to put the correct code?

Result of data:

[image]

Sample code:

```
var prevData = JSON.stringify("");
function startRefreshTable() {
$.getJSON('/tablestatus/', function(data) {

    if (data !== prevData){
        //perform something here
    }
    prevData = data;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare a JSON string to a JavaScript object. 
You need to `JSON.stringify` **both** results.

Since you already stringified your `prevData` variable, you also need to stringify the `data` variable: `JSON.stringify(data) !== prevData`.

Here's the complete code:

```
var prevData = JSON.stringify("");
function startRefreshTable() {
$.getJSON('/tablestatus/', function(data) {

    if (JSON.stringify(data) !== prevData){
        //perform something here
    }
    prevData = data;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "compare a JavaScript object to JSON"? Otherwise I don't know what "a JSON that was not" means. JSON can only exists inside strings in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. Gotta get better at expressing myself in English.